SPMT - Why can't I access to migrate a Site that I just scanned?
In the Sharepoint Migration Tool I can scan a particular URL. It reports no errors and the scan of the site completes successfully.
However, when I go to migrate the very same site in the same session, I get the error, "We are unable to connect to the site you provided. Please check the site URL."
Any ideas?

Suastiastu, have you ever found a solution for this issue?
